Memory usage too high when working with large JS ArrayBuffers
I'm writing some browser code with a lot of large ArrayBuffers. I noticed the memory consumption is unexpectedly large and I'm not sure why that is. I've never worked with ArrayBuffers before and I don't understand it too well. But my test code is short so I'll include it here:
const data = new Uint8Array(
    await get_new_data(output_data_size)
);

async function get_new_data(output_data_size) {
    const output_byte_count = Math.ceil(1024*1024*output_data_size);
    let results_buffer = new ArrayBuffer(output_byte_count);
    return results_buffer;
}

It's supposed to create an ArrayBuffer of size output_data_size megabytes, all elements initialised as zeroes, and that's it. When running the code with output_data_size=128 it should create a 128 MB ArrayBuffer, but the web browser memory consumption increases by 5 GB each time I've tried. I can't see any obvious places where memory leaks could happen. Maybe there is some maximum size for ArrayBuffers?
Edit:
I found that I had a line in my code:
paragraph_element.innerHTML = "lots of debug text" + data;

and the issue went away once I removed the data array from that HTML element.

Did you perhaps remove the problem, while breaking down your code for this question? As is, async/await is completely useless, so I assume it's an excerpt from more complex code. However, running above code on firefox, with output_data_size set to 128, just works for me. Edit: I notice FF has issues when trying to expand the result in the debug console though. That's odd, but unlikely to be a problem with the code itself.

@ASDFGerte I edited the question with what helped me. That sounds like it could possibly be the same issue, adding large data arrays to the HTML or displaying them in the console.

Yeah converting that to a string in DOM sounds like it could open a can of worms. Just UTF-16 with the separator alone would quadruple the space requirement, but while generating you'd eat overhead from the rope structure for the concatenation. The graphics this will produce likely finally kills everything, i mean it's what, 2**28 (more than 256 million) symbols you want to render as text (and parse as html first on top of that)?

It looks like a one-liner to me...
let Size=0; // some value


var data = new Uint8Array(new ArrayBuffer(Math.ceil(1048576*Size))); // NB: not a constant!


// And later when you're done with it give the garbage collector a hand:

data=[];


I tested this and I'm getting the same result unfortunately, and I can't see how it is any different from my previous code, aside from being a one-liner.

Ah it helped me realise though that the issue seems to be that the full contents of the buffer was inserted into the DOM. Idk how that affects things but it seems to have been the cause.

@n-l-i can you expand on that in the OP for posterity?
